# Function that calculates all four types of confidence intervals

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I have to write a function that is able to calculate all four types of confidence interval (of an average). The function should include the parameter "case/type", with that the user can state for which type the confidence interval should be calculated.

I've got the idea that I have to define the four types first and name them accordingly and then I have to work with `if`. But I don´t know what I am supposed to pack into the function.

**Edit:**
I have specified four types of CI:

1. normally distributed, variance known
2. normally distributed, variance unknown
3. arbitrarily distributed, variance known, n>30
4. arbitrarily distributed, variance unknown, n>30

Now I guess I have to start with the function like this:

```
CI<-function(n, mean, sd, z, type){
if(type=="normal_knownvariance"){
result<- mean(x)+c(-1,1)*qnorm(1-z/2)*(sd/sqrt(length(x))                                          
} else if (type=="normal_unknownvariance"){
result<-mean(x)+c(-1,1)*qnorm(1-t/2)*(sqrt(var)/sqrt(length(x)))
} else if (type=="arbitrary_knownvariance_largen){
result<-mean(x)+c(-1,1)*qnorm(1-z/2)*(sd/sqrt(length(x)))
}else if (type=="arbitrary_unknownvariance_largen){
results<-mean(x)+c(-1,1)*qnorm(1-z/2)*(sqrt(var)/sqrt(length(x)))
}
return(result)
}
```

Can I do it like that or have I used "if" or any other part of this function in a wrong way? I am also unsure whether I can simply solve the problem of the arbitrarily distributed types and the types without known variance by just changing z to a t and sd to sqrt(var). I guess I have to make some assumptions in order to be able to use the t- distribution and the guessed variance but I don´t know how exactly.

Best regards!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little bit vague; are you looking for a general outline of how `if` statements work? Or how functions work? Homework questions are allowed on Stack Overflow, but you're most likely to get a good answer if you can make your question specific and show what you've already done. What are the four types of CI you've had specified? (I could write a question that shows the outline of a function including an `if` statement, but if that's not what you need then it will be a waste of both our time ...)

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. You´re right Ben, I will try to specify my question and add my current progress as soon as possible.

Comment: I have now updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

The structure of your function should probably look something like this:

```r
CI <- function(n, mean, sd, z, type) {
   if (type == "normal_knownvariance") {
      result <- mean(x) + c(-1,1)* qnorm(1-z/2)*(sd/sqrt(n))
   } else if (type == "normal_unknownvariance") {
      ## your code here
   } else if (type == "arbitrary_knownvariance_largen") {
     ## your code here
   } else {
     ## your code here
   }
   return(result)
}
```

There are **lots** of possible variations, e.g.

- you could specify `type` as a numeric value instead of a string
- you could specify the assumptions as separate flags (e.g. `distrib` ∈ "normal", "arbitrary", `variance` ∈ "known", "unknown" ...) and use logical combinations (`if (distrib == "normal" && variance == "known")`)
- you could do something similar but use boolean (`TRUE`/`FALSE`) instead: let `normal_distrib` ∈ {`TRUE`, `FALSE`} and say `if (normal_distrib && known_variance)`
- you could use a `switch()` statement or a `dplyr::case_when` statement rather than a series of `if`/`else if` blocks
- you can return results immediately from each `if`-block rather than waiting until the end of the function

etc. etc. etc. etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I´ve just updated my code again. But there is one question left: How can I correctly code the other types e.g. including the t - distribution or unknown variance? Right now, I have just set in the characters for it but I don´t know how to do it properly. Thanks in advance :)